# Reason for introducing z axis

Tags: complex-numbers

When we know that there's a plane(Argand plane) perpendicular to the cartesian plane.Then, why don't we use that model for three dimensional modelling. I mean, why don't we take the x co ordinate in the argand plane and y in the cartesian, this would give us coordinates in three dimensions, doesn't it?

Comment: That would break the symmetry between the 3 Euclidean axes. OTOH, we *kind of* do this in special relativity, where the 4D Minkowski [spacetime interval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_interval) can be written: $$(\Delta s)^2=-(c\Delta t)^2 + (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2$$

Comment: You probably want to learn Quaternions and spatial rotation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion
if you want to satisfy typical expectations of the result.  In essence a reasonable ladder (extension) is: Real⇾Complex⇾Quaternions.  After that things get complicated.